# Ckeditor error in custom build React TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ckeditor5

I made a build from ckEditor online builder I followed the documentation and added the folder in root in my react project
and then I added the folder in package.json through npm install. But when I start my server it gives me.

`
E:/s/a/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignmentediting.d.ts
TypeScript error in E:/s/a/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignmentediting.d.ts(8,23):
',' expected.  TS1005

```
 6 |  * @module alignment/alignmentediting
 7 |  */
```

> 8 | import { Plugin, type Editor } from 'ckeditor5/src/core.js';
> |                       ^
> 9 | /**
> 10 |  * The alignment editing feature. It introduces the {@link module:alignment/alignmentcommand~AlignmentCommand command} and adds
> 11 |  * the `alignment` attribute for block elements in the {@link module:engine/model/model~Model model}.`